# How to correct use derived Read method in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a data structure:

```
data Hybridization = SP | SP2 | SP3 deriving(Eq,Ord,Read,Show)
data AtomProperty = AtomProperty {                                
                                valence' :: Int,
                                lonePairs' :: Int,
                                hybridization' :: [(Int,Hybridization)],    {--Int is an order --}                              
                                electronDonated' :: [(Hybridization,Int)]   
                            } deriving(Read)
```

I'd like to read it from string, but if I try do so:

```
atomPropMap = fromList (read $ "[(\"C\",(4,0,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2),(1,SP)],[(SP2,1)]))," ++
                "(\"H\",(1,0,[],[]))," ++
                "(\"N\",(3,1,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2)],[(SP3,2),(SP2,1)]))," ++
                "(\"O\",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[(SP2,2)])),"  ++
                "(\"S\",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[]))," ++
                "(\"F\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                "(\"Cl\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                "(\"Br\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                "(\"I\",(1,3,[],[]))]" :: [(String,(AtomProperty))])
```

It's results

```
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

but if I construct data structure with standard types it's works:

```
atomPropMap = fromList (read $ "[(\"C\",(4,0,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2),(1,SP)],[(SP2,1)]))," ++
                    "(\"H\",(1,0,[],[]))," ++
                    "(\"N\",(3,1,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2)],[(SP3,2),(SP2,1)]))," ++
                    "(\"O\",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[(SP2,2)])),"  ++
                    "(\"S\",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[]))," ++
                    "(\"F\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                    "(\"Cl\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                    "(\"Br\",(1,3,[],[]))," ++
                    "(\"I\",(1,3,[],[]))]" :: [(String,(Int,Int,[(Int,Hybridization)],[(Hybridization,Int)]))])
```

results, as expected:

```
fromList [("Br",(1,3,[],[])),("C",(4,0,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2),(1,SP)],[(SP2,1)])),("Cl",(1,3,[],[])),("F",(1,3,[],[])),("H",(1,0,[],[])),("I",(1,3,[],[])),("N",(3,1,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2)],[(SP3,2),(SP2,1)])),("O",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[(SP2,2)])),("S",(2,2,[(2,SP2)],[]))]
```

Why one cannot read `AtomProperty` but is able to read `(Int,Int,[(Int,Hybridization)],[(Hybridization,Int)])`, but their structures are equal.

Comment: There are no `AtomProperty` instances in the string, only tuples which is why the first read fails and the second succeeds.  Create an instance of `AtomProperty` in ghci and `show` it.  That's the format you need for read to work properly (you'll also have to derive `Show`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the derived instance of `Read` for record types only parses a string which is formatted as a record type. However, writing your own instance is extremely simple, since there are already read instances for tuples:

```
import GHC.Read

instance Read AtomProperty where
  readPrec = do
    (a,b,c,d) <- readPrec
    return $ AtomProperty a b c d
```

then:

```
>read "(4,0,[(1,SP3),(2,SP2),(1,SP)],[(SP2,1)])" :: AtomProperty
AtomProperty {valence' = 4, lonePairs' = 0, hybridization' = [(1,SP3),(2,SP2),(1,SP)], electronDonated' = [(SP2,1)]}
```

You can do the same sort of thing with the `Show` instance if you like:

```
instance Show AtomProperty where
  show (AtomProperty a b c d) = show (a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could use the 'simple' literal syntax with 'record' constructors... wow. So much typing for nothing o_O

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work with `AtomProperty` because you can't construct an `AtomProperty` like that.

The string for `AtomProperty` would have to look something like

```
"AtomProperty {valence' = <int>,
              lonePairs=<int>,
              hybridization' = <[(Int,Hybridization)]>,
              electronDonated = <[(Hybridization,Int)]>}"
```

-- just like you'd construct it in code. In general, `read` should be the inverse of `show`.

Comment: Well, is there any simple way to read AtomProperty structure from my string without an huge code?

Comment: @shellenberg When using a record structure like that, I would suggest looking at Aeson and parsing it as JSON, but that adds a large dependency to your project.  It's worth it, though, because you can much more easily define how you want the string to be parsed and how to handle errors.

Comment: @shellenberg The best way would be to use some sort of pre-existing format, such as CSV, JSON or XML. Another option is to invent your own format and write a parser for it. The quickest way is to write a conversion function `tupleToAtomProp` that takes a tuple and constructs an `AtomProperty.`